# Dungeon Defenders crashes (Steam)

Tags: nvidia, 64-bit, steam

Hi I have Dungeon Defenders on Ubuntu 13.04 and it the game closes or crashes every 30 minutes (not exactly)

I have Lenovo G580 Intel core i7 6GB RAM.

I have nVidia GEFORCE 710m but it Ubuntu doesn't detect it and says that I have Intel HD graphics, I don't know if that's a problem...

This is the output on Steam

```
dlopen failed trying to load:
/home/abood/.local/share/Steam/linux32/libsteam.so
with error:
/home/abood/.local/share/Steam/linux32/libsteam.so: cannot open shared object file: Too many levels of symbolic links
Game update: AppID 65800 "Dungeon Defenders", ProcID 7943, IP 0.0.0.0:0
Generating new string page texture 152: 256x256, total string texture memory is 1.46 MB
ExecSteamURL: "steam://open/downloads"

(steam:7837): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.
(steam:7837): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.
(over 50 times)
Game update: AppID 65800 "Dungeon Defenders", ProcID 7943, IP 76.177.147.88:55268
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(dungeondefenders-x86)/version(1.0_client)
dlopen failed trying to load:
/home/abood/.local/share/Steam/linux32/libsteam.so
with error:
/home/abood/.local/share/Steam/linux32/libsteam.so: cannot open shared object file: Too many levels of symbolic links
Game update: AppID 65800 "Dungeon Defenders", ProcID 7943, IP 0.0.0.0:0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Game removed: AppID 65800 "Dungeon Defenders", ProcID 7943 

(steam:7837): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.
```

I get this warning message multiple times.

Thank you for helping

Comment: How did you get that error output?  Was it in a log file?  I have a Steam game (CK2) that crashes but there is no error output, it simply exits to desktop.  Have been trying to find log files with no success.  I have an nVidia GeForce as well.  +1 for the question, seems there are several 13.04/steam problems.

Comment: @nbm Run the command 'steam' in the terminal and you will get all the output errors

Comment: Thanks!  FYI I've seen several threads similar to your problem on the Steam forums, you might check there for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to get into the game by unchecking the "Enable Steam Community In-Game" option of the games properties.  It disables the steam interface so thing like chats and invites don't show up but the game opens and runs better than it did on the intel card (I'm using bumblebee to switch to the nvidia card).

Comment: +1 on turning off the community popups.  However, I've also had problems with crashes following steam achievements...which it seems we can't turn off.

Answer (score 0):

If turning off steam community in-game popups does not solve the issue, some people have solved similar problems by disabling the Valve libraries and making Steam default to system libraries instead.  Do this by starting Steam from the terminal with:

$ STEAM_RUNTIME=0 steam

But note that you may then need to install additional libraries.